# Getting ''The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1Docker Container" when building image

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, requirements.txt

Im trying to build a docker image with a python application from cloud shell.

but i keep getting `The command /bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1`
with the following errors:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/python3.9/unicodeobject.h:1026,
                       from /usr/local/include/python3.9/Python.h:97,
                       from numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:4:
      /usr/local/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:45: note: declared here
       Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:45406:25: warning: ‘_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                               (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                               ^
      In file included from /usr/local/include/python3.9/unicodeobject.h:1026,
                       from /usr/local/include/python3.9/Python.h:97,
                       from numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:4:
      /usr/local/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
       static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      error: Command "gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1
 -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/
multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/nu
mpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/priv
ate -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath -c numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.o -MMD -MF build/temp.linux
-x86_64-3.9/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.o.d" failed with exit status 1
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-x4qlx1an/numpy/setup.py'"
'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-x4qlx1an/numpy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.cl
ose();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-9i48k0hd/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /tmp/pip-build
-env-84xomudw/overlay --compile --install-headers /tmp/pip-build-env-84xomudw/overlay/include/python3.9/numpy Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-
env-84xomudw/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.29.13' 'numpy==1.13.3; pytho
n_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version
=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.
```

The dockerfile contains the following:

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there more to the error? It seems like there should be more above.  Also, does pip installing from requirements.txt work locally?

Comment: At which module does `pip` fail? On which hardware are you building the image? `amd64` or `arm`?

Comment: This isn't a proper answer, so I'm going to leave it as a comment: `python:3` points to `python:3.9` now. Try `FROM python:3.8`. I've noticed some pip packages (e.g. `snowflake-connector-python`) have issues building on Python 3.9. This isn't a long-term solution, but it worked for me to quickly get my project back up and running.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this problem and finally got the solution from Heroku. Actually, New Python applications on Heroku use the Python runtime indicated in Specifying a Python version (by default new version of python). To solve this issue, you have to create a runtime.txt file in which you write the python version that you have used to create an environment. Heroku support the following python version-

1. python-3.9.4
2. python-3.8.9
3. python-3.7.10
4. python-3.6.13

Below is the snapshot of the runtime.txt file

[image]

After creating this file put it into the root directory of our app.

[image]

After that follow the procedure as usual for deployment.